# In terms of SEO is using a forward slash in the url best practice?

Tags: seo, url

domain.com/test which is a content not a folder and I would expect it to be without a forward s lash at the end for that reason, am I wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as you are consistent. If both URLs pull up the same content then you'll have issues with duplicate content. You should pick one format (I prefer with the trailing slash for the same reasons you do) and do a 301 redirect of the URLs with the trailing slash to it. I would also use canonical URLs to make sure Google know which one is the one you wish to have indexed.